# Filter array of objects when value exists on property array

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is my array:

```
data = [
        { id: 1, code: "A20", type: ["X", "S"] },
        { id: 2, code: "A21", type: ["S"] },
        { id: 3, code: "B02", type: ["X", "S"] },
        { id: 4, code: "C02", type: ["X"] },
        { id: 5, code: "C35", type: ["S"] }
];
```

I would like to return a filtered array by type. So if type contains 'X' the new array should contain objects with id 1, 3 and 4. This is what I am doing right now:

```
filteredArray = this.data.filter(
                       obj => obj.type.includes("X")
                );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What goes wrong? Are errors reported? Are you sure `this.data` is the correct way to refer to your array? (It's not clear from what's posted.)

Comment: No errors. Just an empty array...

Comment: Your code as posted works correctly. Of course, there may be other code that you did not post that would explain what's going on.

Comment: Your code work fine

Comment: exclude this in this.data.filter....... simply use data.filter.......

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work in browser console.

Because `data` is assigned globally and `this` will refer to 'current_window'. Hence `window.data.filter` will work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [
    { id: 1, code: "A20", type: ["X", "S"] },
    { id: 2, code: "A21", type: ["S"] },
    { id: 3, code: "B02", type: ["X", "S"] },
    { id: 4, code: "C02", type: ["X"] },
    { id: 5, code: "C35", type: ["S"] }
];

let filteredArray = data.filter(
    obj => obj.type.includes("X")
);

console.log(filteredArray)
```